# Error when generating app with Bowline for Ruby

Tags: ruby, macos, osx-snow-leopard

When I try to generate an app with `bowline-gen app helloworld` almost all the

```
... more files
... more files
[ADDED]  config
[ADDED]  config/initializers
[ADDED]  config/first_run
[ADDED]  app_first_run
[ADDED]  .gitignore
[ADDED]  public/icon.png
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:1216:in `chmod': No such file or directory - /Users/ma/dev/ruby/_bowline/helloworld/script (Errno::ENOENT)
```

I have tried reinstalling both bowline and bowline-bundle separately with

```
sudo gem uninstall bowline
sudo gem uninstall bowline-bundle
```

But I have no clue where I am at. Could someone please enlighten me on this issue, would be very greatful!

Comment: After some searching I found this link on the [Bowline bugtracker](https://github.com/maccman/bowline/issues#issue/13) on what might be up. I don't understand it anyway, but some of you might..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Ruby 1.8, bowline [requires 1.9.1 at least](http://bowlineapp.com/#install)